# Getting numerical elements from Odometer syntax in Cypress

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cypress

I'm currently trying to get the balance in a webpage using Cypress. However, the balance in the webpage is using Odometer (which animates the numbers increasing and decreasing). This ReactJS component separates each digit into span tags

In my screenshot, the numbers I need are separated into `<span class="odometer-value">1</span>`. So for example, the digits `1 486` would be stored in different lines.

How would I access those separate span tags and then group them together in Cypress? If the number is `10 000` I would still want it to function similarly.
[image: Code snippet of inspect page]

Answer (score 0):

You could try a reducer inside a `.then()` callback

```js
cy.get('span.odometer-value')                        // selects all elements
  .then($spans => {
    const value = [...$spans]                        // turn node list into an array
      .reduce((acc, $span) => { 
        const text = $span.innerText.replace('\u00A0','');
        return acc.concat(text);                     // append to accumulator  
      }, '');                              

    return +(value);                                 // convert text to number
  })
  .should('be.gt', 140);                             // test it
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easier if you let Cypress do the concatenating for you

```js
cy.get('span.odometer-value')
  .invoke('text')        // instead of .each() - Cypress concats all the text for you
  .then(formatString)    // remove the nbsp
  .then(text => +text)   // convert to a number if you want
  .should('be.gt', 140);

function formatString(text) {
  return text.replace('\u00A0','').trim();
}
```